# Is my practice of implementing responsive in react good?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css-grid

I just need some advice on what I am doing to create a responsive page that uses react components is okay.

I am using window.matchmedia to match media query and re rendering everytime window size is set or changes.

```
function reportWindowSize() {
  let isPhone = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)");

  if (isPhone.matches) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Vodplayer isPhone="true" />
        <Feedback isPhone="true" />
        <HighlightsDropdown isPhone="true"> </HighlightsDropdown>
        <Viewcount isPhone="true"></Viewcount>
        <Carousel isPhone="true" />
        <Ruler isPhone="true" />
      </React.Fragment>,
      document.getElementById("small-container-id")
    );
  } else {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Vodplayer isPhone="false" />
        <Highlights isPhone="false" />
        <Viewcount isPhone="false"></Viewcount>
        <Carousel isPhone="false" />
        <Feedback isPhone="false" />
        <Ruler isPhone="false" />
      </React.Fragment>,
      document.getElementById("small-container-id")
    );
  }
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
window.onload = reportWindowSize;
```

I Thing is I want to change components at 999px and maybe in future at more breakpoints. but this way react is rendering 500 times if i change width of my webpage by 500px. isn't this very inefficient ? I tried using debounce but that way I am able to see components add and remove with even a delay of 100 ms and that doesn't look pretty. What are other ways I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *the thing is I want to change

Comment: it seems you need something like this [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive)

Comment: *"but this way react is rendering 500 times if i change width of my webpage by 500px"*  Did you find evidence of that? I would think that React, like CSS or plain JS, would skip some steps when you resize the screen in one smooth movement.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, I did console.log right inside render and it was rendering it again and again, however after using the package mentioned by Mashiro in above comment, the console.log was run or render was run right after crossing the breakpoint. I am exploring that package further...

Comment: @Mashiro I checked that library out, but it uses Hooks and I just have hugs class components hence I cannot use that library.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can get away with using CSS alone for responsive adaptations. When you do need JS to make changes, you probably want to do so in a way that doesn't completely litter your codebase with noise.

You could use a simple hook, like [this one that is part of Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/), to listen for changes inside of just the components that need this information.

Also, for what it's worth, you're passing truthy values to `isPhone` in both branches of your conditional (`!!"false" // is true`).

Comment: Can this be done without Hooks? I already have a huge webapp thats build just on class components and those components are so big I dare not try to convert them to functional components ..

Comment: @xaovnumwsercz Yeah, absolutely, you would just encapsulate that functionality in a class method on your component instead. That said, you can use hooks in functional components alongside class-based components too.